# Dice game in the Mid-Autumn Festival

Tags: probability, dice

I have the following question. I solved them but I need to double check that my answer is correct.

> In a dice game that is played during the Mid-Autumn Festival, participants take turn throwing six dice into a large bowl. If certain combinations show up, the person gets a prize. Below, we describe the important combinations and the prize assigned to each combination:
>
> 1. six 1’s or six 4’s show up (1st prize)
> 2. exactly five of any number show up (2nd prize)
> 3. the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 show up (3rd prize)
> 4. exactly three 4’s show up (4th prize)
>
> What is the probability of winning each of these prizes?

Here are my answers:

1. $\frac1{6^6}+\frac1{6^6}$
2. $\frac{\binom61\binom65}{6^6}$
3. I am confused here. The first solution I thought of was $\frac1{6!}$, but my friend said the solution was $\frac16(1-\frac16)(1-\frac26)(1-\frac36)(1-\frac46)(1-\frac56)$.
4. $\frac1{6^3}(1-\frac16)^3$

Comment: Ok, The second part that I wanna double check that is correct. Suppose there are ten people playing this game and in each round everyone gets a turn. By sheer luck, you have the first turn at each round. Now, there is only one first prize so the first person who throws the right combination wins the prize. what is the probability that you will win it in the fifth round ?

Comment: is it solved by binomial  for each round ?

Answer (score 1):

There are $6^6$ equally likely outcomes (counting order of the dice).  Of these, $6!$ win third prize.  So the probability of third prize is $6!/6^6$.

Comment: @OP (which is the same as your friends answer)

Answer (score 0):

The second answer is incorrect.  It should be $$\frac{6(6)(5)}{6^6} = \frac{180}{46656} = \frac{5}{1296},$$  because there are $6$ ways to choose which number is the $5$-of-a-kind, $5$ ways to choose the singleton (which cannot be the same number as the $5$-of-a-kind), and $6$ positions/permutations of the singleton among the $5$-of-a-kind.

Answer (score 0):

First Prize: Aye, Okay.

Second Prize: the favoured event is a selection of *two* numbers, the penttuple and single, and dice for the pentuple.

$$\dfrac{\binom 6 1\binom 5 1\binom 65}{6^6}$$

Third Prize: the favoured event is some *permutation* of all six distinct numbers.  How many ways can that happen out of the $6^6$ total?

$$\dfrac{\bbox[0.25ex, border: 0.1ex dashed green]{\qquad ?}}{6^6}$$

Fourth Prize: the favoured event is a selection of three dice to show `4` and the three other dice must each show one of the 5 not-`4` numbers.

$$\dfrac{\binom{6}{3}\bbox[0.25ex, border: 0.1ex dashed green]{\qquad ?}}{6^6}$$

Comment: Ok, The second part that I wanna double check that is correct. Suppose there are ten people playing this game and in each round everyone gets a turn. By sheer luck, you have the first turn at each round. Now, there is only one first prize so the first person who throws the right combination wins the prize. what is the probability that you will win it in the fifth round ?is it solved by binomial for each round ?